# How to run js functionality in native android when phonegap app is closed??? where background service runs properly?

Tags: cordova, webview, background, background-service

When app is closed or destroyed background android native service is running properly...but js functions are not calling due to webview destructions...Is there any way/ example code to run js functions when app is closed...Help friends sky is falling on me...

Answer (score 0):

Install the Background plugin to run the Phonegap functions when the app is in background or is destroyed.

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode